# Prove that 3 divides $a \times b \times ( a^2 − b^2 )$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

This is so random and I can't get to the key. All I'm thinking about is to proof that $a \times b \times ( a^2 - b^2 )$ is three numbers that are followed by each other but I can't prove it.

Comment: how can i proof that? if b=1 we can say it's correct but what if b doesnt equal 1

Answer (score 7):

You can write
$$ a b (a^2 - b^2) = a b (a+b) (a-b).$$
If $a$ or $b$ is divisible by 3, we're done. If $a$ and $b$ both leave remainder 1 or 2 when divided by 3, $a-b$ is divisible by 3, and if $a$ leaves remainder 1 and $b$ leaves remainder 2 when divided by 3 (or vice versa), $a+b$ is divisible by 3.

Comment: thank you so much that's very helpful

Comment: Nice +1...but simpler: if $\;a\;$ isn't divisible by $\;3\;$ , then $\;a^2=1\pmod 3\;$ , so if $\;a,\,b\;$ aren't divisible by three, then $\;a^2-b^2=1-1=0\pmod3\;$

Comment: Oh that's cool, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Your argument is good, but instead of saying "divisible by $3$ modulo $1$" you should say "is congruent to $1$ modulo $3$" or "leaves remainder $1$ when divided by $3$"

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thanks, you're right. I've edited the answer.